# Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

Before chrome got updated to v120, my undetected-chromedriver crawler would run without any issues. After the update, I am encountering this error:

Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000 (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.71)

This error has been coming up during every execution of the program and changing the code structure or closing the UC instance and restarting it mid-way is also not resolving it.

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    browser = uc.Chrome(options= options)  

    ua = UserAgent()
    userAgent = ua.random

    browser.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'driver', {get: () => undefined})")
    browser.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": userAgent})
```

Any idea on how to go about this?

(I executed a web crawler using undetected-chromedriver. The browser window throws up the above mentioned error after running for some time.)